# How to properly kill MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, linux, shutdown

I have CentOS 64bit with CPanel installed and I use

```
service mysql stop
```

However, it keeps doing ..... for minutes and it never stops. It used to be instant. Any idea why it does that and how to fix? Right now I have to do `killall -9 mysql` but is there a better way?

The server is also very very active.